# SceneKit: slow loading of UIView after contact between two nodes

Tags: ios, swift, physics, contacts, scenekit

I just found a really odd behavior with Scene Kit. I created a clean project to see if this would happen, and it did. Consider the following `GameViewController` class:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        label.textColor = .whiteColor()
        label.text = "Test"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // Controller
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Scene
        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        // Scene View
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.scene = scene

        // Camera
        let camera = SCNCamera()
        camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
        camera.orthographicScale = 8

        // Camera Node
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -3, y: 7.5, z: 10)
        cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: -0.5, z: 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // Light
        let light = SCNLight()
        light.type = SCNLightTypeDirectional

        // Light Node
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = light
        lightNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(-1, -0.5, 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // Box Shape
        let geometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
        geometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        // Upper Box
        let box = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        box.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: nil)
        box.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        box.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(box)

        // Bottom Box
        let box2 = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        box2.position.y -= 5
        box2.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Static, shape: nil)
        box2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
        box2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        box2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(box2)

    }
}
```

What happens here is, we create a `SCNScene`, then we add the camera/lightning and create two boxes that will collide. We also set the controller as a delegate for the physics contact delegate.

But the important code is at the top, when the contact between the two objects occurs. We create an `UILabel` and position it at the top left of the screen. But here is the problem: **It takes around seven seconds for the label to display.** And it seems to always be this time. This seems rather odd, but you can try it yourself: just create a SceneKit project (using Swift), and replace the controller code with the one I provided.

Additional note: if you add `print("a")` in the `physicsWorld()` function, it will run immediately, so the code is being run at the right time, but for some reason the `UILabel` isn't displaying right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought your scene wasn't being rendered after the contact; hence not displaying the label, so put a `scnView.playing = true` line in. However, this resulted in the label never being displayed.

Next thought was that you're trying to do something on a thread you shouldn't be. Modifying UIKit views should really only be done on the main thread, and it's not clear what thread calls the `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` functions. Given it's relatively easy to ensure it does run on the main thread...

```
func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        label.textColor = .whiteColor()
        label.text = "Test"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

This fixes the delay for me, and also works with `scnView.playing = true`.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't expecting that issue as the code worked perfectly on a SpriteKit project. This seemed to solve the problem.